# Seeing "ImportError: No module names map_reduce" in GridMap when running example

Tags: python, cluster-computing, pickle, sungridengine

I've created an SGE cluster on google cloud platform. I installed GridMap on python 2.7.5 and and trying to run their example python jobs which can be found here
https://github.com/pygridtools/gridmap/tree/master/examples

both example just create 4 jobs that calculate various factorials and return the results. When I try running "map_reduce.py" I see errors on the worker machines stating "ImportError: No module names map_reduce"

I've isolated the error to a zload call which decompresses using bz2 and then tries to load the data with pickle

```
def zloads(pickled_data):
    """
    loads pickleable object from bz2 compressed string
    :param pickled_data: BZ2 compressed byte sequence
    :type pickled_data: bytes
    :returns: An unpickled version of the compressed byte sequence.
    """
    return pickle.loads(bz2.decompress(pickled_data))
```

The "pickled_data" object comes from a call to a "recv" from a zmq socket call

```
# Get reply
msg = zloads(zsocket.recv())
```

All gridmap code can be found here

https://github.com/pygridtools/gridmap/tree/master/gridmap

Appreciate any helper or suggestion anyone can offer.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer. I ended up stepping through the pickle code as it tried to load the pickle file. I noticed it was trying to import the python module was trying to run, in this case 'map_reduce', to get access to the function defined in the file ('compute_factorial') but that it was looking in a directory path from the originating machine. So I tried running the job from a shared directory that all the workers have access to and voila, success.

This was a fundamental misunderstanding on my part as to how gridmap works. I thought it actually packaged up the python code and ran it on the worker machines. In fact it appears is packages a pointer to that code and expects to be able to access it from the worker machines from the same directory path.